# C# SHA-2 (512) Base64 encoded hash

Tags: c#, encryption

Looking for a way to do the following in C# from a string.

[public static String sha512Hex(byte[] data)](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha512Hex%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Calculates the SHA-512 digest and returns the value as a hex string.

Parameters:
data - Data to digest
Returns:
SHA-512 digest as a hex string

```
    private static string GetSHA512(string text)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] hashValue;
        byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(text);
        SHA512Managed hashString = new SHA512Managed();
        string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(message);
        string hex = "";
        hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(UE.GetBytes(encodedData));
        foreach (byte x in hashValue)
        {
            hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }
        return hex;
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Would [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx) be what you need?

```
var alg = SHA512.Create();
alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));
BitConverter.ToString(alg.Hash).Dump();
```

Executed in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) produces:

> EE-26-B0-DD-4A-F7-E7-49-AA-1A-8E-E3-C1-0A-E9-92-3F-61-89-80-77-2E-47-3F-88-19-A5-D4-94-0E-0D-B2-7A-C1-85-F8-A0-E1-D5-F8-4F-88-BC-88-7F-D6-7B-14-37-32-C3-04-CC-5F-A9-AD-8E-6F-57-F5-00-28-A8-FF

To create the method from your question:

```
public static string sha512Hex(byte[] data)
{
    using (var alg = SHA512.Create())
    {
        alg.ComputeHash(data);
        return BitConverter.ToString(alg.Hash);
    }
}
```

Comment: didnt work as I had hoped. the documentation states that I need to convert a string to "SHA-2 (512) Base64 encoded hash"

Comment: Yeah, OK, I didn't read the title all the careful, you should mention the "-2" part in your question as well. Don't know if there is a SHA-2 512-bit implementation in .NET but probably is.

Comment: You sure SHA512 isn't SHA-2? Other websites states that it is SHA-2 512-bit.

Comment: Do you have a test-case with predefined input and output?

Comment: that's not a hex output... it has been encoded somehow. You need better documentation.

Comment: the random key, do you have a specific key that would help produce that specific output you have above?

Comment: What is a "key" here? is it a number? a set of characters? a guid?

Comment: As with all salted hashes, if you don't have the salt, the hash is worthless. You need to talk to the people who gave you the example and ask for a specific example.

Answer (score 12):

Got this to work.  Taken from [here](http://www.adventuresindevelopment.com/2009/06/02/hash-passwords-in-c-and-visual-basic-using-sha-512/) and modified a bit.

```
    public static string CreateSHAHash(string Phrase)
    {
        SHA512Managed HashTool = new SHA512Managed();
        Byte[] PhraseAsByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Phrase));
        Byte[] EncryptedBytes = HashTool.ComputeHash(PhraseAsByte);
        HashTool.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
    }
```

Comment: That isn't returning a "Hex string" but a base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Better memory management:

```
    public static string SHA512Hash(string value)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes;

        using (var hashTool = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            encryptedBytes = hashTool.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(value)));
            hashTool.Clear();
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
    }
```

Comment: That isn't returning a "Hex string" but a base64 encoded string.